# .netcore css from site.css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

**what I want to happen:**

pull the css from my site.css file

**cshtml:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../wwwroot/css/site.css" type="text/css">
<div class="text-center indexBG">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

**site.css:**

```
.indexBG {
    background-image: url(/images/image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}
```

**What I tried:**

I was able to make it work by adding a `<style>` tag in the cshtml; but I want to be able to re-use the styling for other pages and avoid repeated code. would much rather refrense the site.css

Comment: What do you mean `e-use the styling for other pages and avoid repeated code`?.net core will  add site.css in _layout.cshtml by default,so you can use css in it in each cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

By default, this line is in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
[image]